# Using PHP to display a file/image on another webpage (Ex. Cloudapp or Droplr)

Tags: php, cloud, ads

I'm looking for a way to display a file or image on another page like used in Cloudapp or Droplr. I ask, because I would like to display advertisements on those pages for where the user views their files. To the best of my knowledge this can be done with PHP.

I have a system step and developed already for the user to upload their file(s) to a folder on my server. All I need now is to display ads on the file pages...

Comment: [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) will be your friend here...

Comment: Really? Why can't I just do something like this, http://zkinformer.com/blog_detail.php?post_id=34

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant to fetch them from another web page, and display them on your own, but after re-reading this is probably not the case - so what exactly is you problem? Can't you just save your files somewhere that is web-accessible, and reference them in the `src` of your image?

Comment: I can, but I want to be able to have the user who uploads the file to view the uploaded item on a page that can display an advertisement. The same for all files that are uploaded to my server.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? How to place the advertisement on the page? This would depend on where the advertisement is coming from...

Comment: The problem is how can I make a page render all of the desired content including an advertisement if for say you go to the page www.example.com/images/images.php?=example.png and be able to see both the advertisement and the image.

Comment: Please add your existing code for `images.php` as referenced above...

Comment: Dude, like I said. I all have is the upload script... That's why I'm asking for advice on how to script this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic framework for a file that displays an image and an advert:

```
<?php

  // Path to the directory that holds the images
  $imageDir = 'images/';

  // Make sure an image was requested
  if (!isset($_GET['image'])) {
    exit('No image requested to display');
  }

  // Full path to image
  $imagePath = $imageDir.$_GET['image'];

  // Make sure the image exists
  if (!is_file($imagePath)) {
    exit("Image doesn't exist!");
  }

?>
<html>

  <head>
    <title><?php echo $imagePath; ?></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <!-- HTML for advert goes here -->
      <div>Buy Stuff! It's great for wasting your money on!</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- Display the image -->
      <img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is missing many pieces, but then so is you description of what you want...

Comment: I love it! Sorry, this is what I was trying to ask. So, when going to  the file this code is placed in, would I address the image like this /images/images.php?=test.png/ ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, you would address it like `/images.php?image=test.png`, assuming you put it in the root of your web server, and that the images are stored in a directory called `images`. Note that `?=test.png` is not a good approach, you need `?image=test.png` (use any name you like, it doesn't have to be `image`) - then you can get at the data in `$_GET['image']`

Comment: Okay, awesome. One more question though. Everything seems to be working, except the image comes up as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Where are your images stored? For the above script to work as it is, your images need to be stored in a directory called `images`, and the file should be placed in the directory above it. So if your images are in `/var/root/images`, the script should be placed in `/var/root`

Comment: I renamed the directory to /root/public_html/users/uploads instead of images. I also renamed images to uploads in the php script.

Comment: ...and where did you place this script? It should be at `/root/public_html/users/images.php`, based on what you say you have done.

Comment: Yes, it's setup like that. Still nothing appears.

Comment: Never mind, I changed the directory permissions on accident. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with simply outputting

```
<img src="http://theotherserver/path/to/image" />
```

from your script. You can certainly have PHP fetch the image and proxy it for your user, then then you're doubling your bandwidth bill (1 hit to fetch the image droplr->server, and then another hit to send the image from server->user).

Comment: I don't think you understand, I'm not fetching anything from Droplr or any other file sharing service. I just want to be able to use PHP to render images or files on my server with advertisements on them after a user uploads a file. I just mentioned those services because I want to do the same thing.

Comment: Oh, well, then just have `<img src="somescript.php">` and have that script output a gif/jpeg/png.

Comment: What about going to a url, rather than having an image source? Like this, www.example.com/images/images.php?=example.png and then on that page display the advertisement...

Comment: And how do you plan to tell the browser to interpret that url as an image? If you want the ad to show inside a page, you'll have to use an img tag, otherwise you get JUST an image taking up the whole window.

Comment: An ad is just an image or a flash movie or whatever. Just because it's an ad doesn't mean it gets treated differently from any other content on th eweb. If you want to display an ad on a page, you have to have some way of embedding the stuff required to display the ad in that page, and that depends on WHAT the ad is. It's just something in a webpage. Don't overthink this.

Comment: So, could I make a PHP file and upon that file loading use the url in the browser to load the image onto that PHP file's page?